# SharePoint list calculated column formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

Is it possible to make a SharePoint list calculated column so that if value equals to Italy it returns '1', otherwise '0'.

I am using:

```
=IF([Question 1]= "Italy" , "1", "0")
```

This always returns "1".

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of list data in Question 1 column? Your formula looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems fine to me.

```
=IF([Question 1] = "Italy", "1", "0")
```

Make sure you have below things correctly:

1. Set **The data type returned from this formula is** to **Single line of text** like:

   [image]

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (It is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Ganesh, thanks a million. I had a typo on the formula. 
Have a great weekend!